# Web Server won't load with Public IP outside the LAN

Tags: networking, router, ip, webserver, wan

I recently set up a web server on my Raspberry Pi with a static IP of 192.168.0.28. I opened private and public port 80 through the router to this IP; it is a D-Link DIR-655 with the latest firmware of 1.37. I also set up a DDNS on www.noip.org targeting my public IP.

I can connect to the web server from any computer on the LAN with the static IP, public IP, and DDNS. My problem is when I try using the DDNS or the public IP from a client outside the LAN, I get redirected to the static IP of 192.168.0.28 and the page never loads.

So it seems outsiders get navigated either to the Raspberry Pi, but the Raspberry Pi can't deliver the site back out, or to the IP of 192.168.0.28 on their network. Could somebody help me figure out how to get this web server to load over WAN?

Comment: You need to set the DDNS to the public IP address of your router, and port forward that to your Raspberry Pi in order to connect to it from the WAN

Answer (score 0):

You talked about opening ports but we are not sure if you setup the port forwarding correctly. Here is a step by step [guide](http://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/port-forwarding-on-a-dir-655-v1-32-router/) for your specific router.

You will fill in a name (for example Pi-web) and open TCP port 80 to your 192.168.0.28 IP.

The best test to verify everything is:

1) from a PC on the same network type the http://192.168.0.28 (verify the web server is running)

2) From a PC on the same network visit www.whatismyip.com and type the public IP to the browser (verify the port forward works)

3) From a different connection (like phone or a Starbucks) type the public IP from step 2 (assuming no reboot of your router). This will verify your ISP is not blocking port 80. if this fail, move the web server on the PI to another port - like 6666 and try again with http://192.168.0.28:6666 in step 1 and try again step 2 and 3 with adding the ":6666" to go around your ISP block.

Comment: Not sure if it mattered, but to start off I opened port 80 to both TCP and UDP. I got through step 1 and 2 fine and www.portchecktool.com even agreed that port 80 was unblocked. On step 3, though, I could not get my web server to load. When I switched the port to :6666, www.portchecktool.com said it was restricted along with failing to repeat steps 1-3.